# Silverman's theorem 3.1 on Weierstrass p function convergence.

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

In the Arithmetic of Elliptic curves, VI.2 Theorem 3.1 (a), Silverman states the Eisenstein series $G_{2k}(\Lambda) = \sum_{\omega \in \Lambda \backslash 0} \frac{1}{\omega^{2k}}$ converges absolutely for all $k > 1$. In Theorem 3.1(b) he says part (a) implies that the Weierstrass $\wp$ function is also absolutely convergent. But in the proof of this he only bounds each term of the Weierstrass function by the following:
$$ \left | \frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2} - \frac{1}{\omega^2} \right | \leq \frac{10 |z| }{ |\omega|^2}$$ (where $\omega$ is the lattice point). Isn't this insufficient because $G_{2k}(\Lambda)$ does not converge for $k=1$? I see other sources (e.g. [https://math.berkeley.edu/~dcorwin/math185S20/SS-elliptic.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Edcorwin/math185S20/SS-elliptic.pdf)) bound each term by $O(\omega^{-3})$, and that argument I do follow.

Am I missing something here in Silverman's proof?

Comment: Just a typo ${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mistake is noted on p. 18 of the [errata on Silverman's webpage](https://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/AEC/AECErrata.pdf).

Comment: Great thank you, I must have been looking at an old version of the errata somehow.